# Problem with redirection in handler laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

How about, I have a small problem, I want in the case that there is a 405 error redirect to 'login', but I still can not.

```html
<?php
  public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        
          if($this->isHttpException($exception))
        {
            switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
                //access denied
                case 401:
                    return response()->view('usuario.error', [], 401);  
                break;
                // not found
                case 404:
                    return response()->view('usuario.error', [], 404);
                break;
                // internal error
                case 403:
                    return response()->view('usuario.error', [], 403);  
                break;
                // internal error
                case 500:
                    return response()->view('usuario.error', [], 500);  
                break;
                  // internal error
                case 405:
                    return response():redirect()->guest(route('/login'));
                break;

                default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }

    }
```

This is what I try in error 405, but I do not achieve the redirection

Comment: Shouldn't that be `response()->redirect()->...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe?

```
response()->redirectTo()->SEND()
```

Comment: thanks Elmar,  I solved it like that  redirect()->route('login');